# Boom stand or articulating clamp trinocular microscope?

Tags: microscope

What's the downside for each? Is the boom stand more steady, but takes up more desk space?
I'm debating between the two, but I can't seen to find any info on the pros/cons of each type.

Comment: I've heard people say the baseplate with the sliding boom is more stable. If I got one, I would opt for the clamp with articulating arm though since that's less weight in shipping. It's not like you solder with a very high magnification anyways.

Comment: Both must be clamped to a secure (granite) table if using high mag. on a long reach.

Comment: granite? So I just have a pine work bench that I would clamp it to. Are you saying it'll bend the desk due to the weight?

Comment: Unless you're working on large boards, just get the simple biology lab base and throw something over the hole in it.  The fancier stands invariably just cause problems - maybe the really fancy ones are okay, but the moderately priced ones are not.  In one situation we ended up just chucking the arm into storage, turning the very heavy base that was supposed to hold it around backwards, mounting the focusing rack directly to that and aiming it at the workbench with no base in the way at all.

Comment: @ChrisStratton That's good to know. Unfortunately, I can never find ones with a wide, thin, biology base with quite the features I want

Comment: Also beware it costs a lot to get a useful trinocular setup - first, the cheap ones lose one eyepiece when you use that.  And even with the better simulfocus ones and a reducer, the camera probably wan't see the entire field of view of the eyepiece, nor can a single camera see 3d defects like a partially tombstoned resistor.  Unless you're doing something like training where two people need to see at one, consider just getting a cheap camera to replace one eyepiece when you need a documentation photo is likely more cost effective.

Comment: yea, but I want to have the boards I'm working on in a pcb holder and having the ability to just swing in the scope when you need to is much more appealing than trying to deal with a base and the pcb stand at the same time. You just end up getting frustrated trying to position both.

Comment: Also need good light source ,, low budget? https://www.aliexpress.com/i/32977438146.html